# Slack attachments - Image next to text instead of below

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to format a Slack attachment with an image so that the picture shows next to the text instead of below. This is possible by using a thumbnail, but as the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments) mentions, the image is resized to 75 x 75 pixels.

Does anybody know if it is possible to display a full-size image next to the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to have your image next to the text, you only option is thumbnail.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you!